# Erro >> TESTE500K.c:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `INSERE' <<

Tags: c, lista, ponteiro, lista-encadeada

Galera, estou tentando criar uma lista mas está dando esses erros
TESTE500K.c:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `INSERE'

TESTE500K.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `IMPRIME'

[Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Teria que fazer com String (char*) que é outro problema, mas resolvi testar primeiro com char só que não está funcionando.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    struct agenda {
        int tel;
        char nome;
        struct agenda *prox;
    };
    typedef struct agenda Agenda;
    typedef Agenda *Ponteiro;

    void INSERE (Ponteiro *, int , char);
    void IMPRIME (Ponteiro);


    int main (){
        Ponteiro inicio = NULL;
        int telefone;
        char NOME;
        int escolha;
        printf ("DIGITE: \n 1 para Inserir \n 2 para Imprimir \n 3 para Finalizar \n");
        scanf ("%d", &escolha);
        if (escolha == 1){
            printf ("DIGITE O NOME: \n");
            scanf ("%c", &NOME);
            printf ("DIGITE O NUMERO: \n");
            scanf ("%d", &telefone);
            INSERE (&inicio, telefone, NOME);

        }
        else if (escolha == 2){
            IMPRIME (inicio);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
        void INSERE (Ponteiro *sPtr, int novo_telefone, char novo_nome){
            Ponteiro novo, anterior, atual;
            novo = malloc (sizeof(Agenda));
            if (novo != NULL){
                novo->tel = novo_telefone;
                novo->nome = novo_nome;
                anterior = NULL;
                atual = *sPtr; 
                while (atual != NULL){
                    anterior = atual;
                    atual = atual ->prox;
                    if (anterior == NULL) {
                        novo->prox = *sPtr;
                        *sPtr = novo;
                    }
                    else{
                        anterior->prox = novo;
                        novo->prox = atual;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        void IMPRIME(Ponteiro atual) {
            if (atual == NULL)
                printf( "A Agenda esta vazia.\n\n" ) ;

            else {
                printf( "A lista eh:\n");
                while (atual != NULL) {
                    printf("%c", atual->nome);
                    printf("%d", atual->tel);

                    atual = atual -> prox;
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Olá Jorge! Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Gostaria que você pudesse editar um pouco melhor sua pergunta, está um pouco difícil de entender, veja [este link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para ter uma ideia de como editá-la.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após

```
 else {
        return 0;
    }
```

deveria haver mais uma chave, que fecharia a função `main()`. Sem a chave, você está basicamente definindo as funções `IMPRIME()` e `INSERE()` dentro de `main()`, o que é impossível em C, logo as funções não estão sendo criadas, e o seu compilador não sabe o que fazer.

Também é necessário que você remova a última chave do programa, já que é lá que o seu programa está acabando atualmente.

Comment: Na verdade o GCC permite a criação de funções dentro de outras funções como extensão de linguagem, mas essas funções internas não têm acesso ao escopo léxico circundante como as funções em javascript ou lua, por exemplo. A Wikipédia em inglês tem um ótimo artigo sobre [o problema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funarg_problem).

Comment: @Wtrmute Obrigado pelas observações.